# HTML select tag activation and deactivation

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make html select tag only activated when a check box is checked,how can i??

Comment: You will need JavaScript for that. Consider adding the `javascript` tag.

Comment: @Sime: At first I thought that was some cruel sarcasm, saying that adding `<javascript>` to the HTML would solve the problem. Then I figured it out :D

Comment: LOL yeah, my comment should have been phrased better. In case OdO didn't understand it, what I mean is that this issue requires JavaScript, so that it would be proper to add `javascript` to this question's tags. As for now, the question has only the `html` tag set.

Answer (score 3):

Using Javascript:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

    if(document.getElementById("myCheckbox").checked) { 
      document.getElementById("mySelect").disabled = "";
    } 
    else { 
      document.getElementById("mySelect").disabled = "disabled"; 
    }

</script>
```

When this code is called, it checks if box is checked and disables select as appropriate.

Or, with PHP/HTML:

```
<form action='' method='post'>
<select <?PHP if($_POST['myCheckbox']==1) { echo "disabled='disabled'"; } ?> >
 <option>blah</option>
</select>

<input type='checkbox' name='myCheckbox' value='1' />
</form>
```

When the form is submitted, this checks if box has been `POST`ed and disables select as appropriate.

Comment: Isn't the `disabled` property boolean?

Comment: I thought that myself, but I've found it sometimes breaks with boolean values...unfortunately I forget the exact circumstances.

Comment: Steve ,both the two codes don't work,and the select is enabled all the time

Answer (score 2):

```
function handler() {
    var checkbox = document.getElementById("myCheckbox");
    var select = document.getElementById("mySelect");

    select.disabled = !checkbox.checked;
}
```

I tested the disabled property: It can be set to either `true` / `false` or `"disabled"` / `""`. Both methods work in all browsers.

(I tested in Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Opera and IE9 beta)

Comment: Is there a reason you don't use `select.disabled = !checkbox.checked` other than readability?

Comment: @Dave I haven't thought of it. Good idea. However, I am not sure if setting boolean values to the disabled property is cross-browser safe.